fresh 24.04 on dell desktop ... ethernet not working
just did a fresh install of 24.04 on new dell xps ... system is up however no ethernet found ... lshw -C network shows UNCLAIMED ethernet -> one for intel and one for realtek ... any ideas how to repair ?

So it is finding the Ethernet just does not have an active driver.

@user3289952 Please add details of the required drivers by editing your original question.
